# Start application even if DLL isn't found?

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

Suppose I have

1. main() in main.exe
2. functionA() in dllA
3. functionB() in dllB

In main.exe,

```
int main()
{
   if(1)
    {
       functionA();
    }
    else
    {
       functionB();
    }
}
```

Suppose I do not have dllB but only dllA and I still want to launch the application main.exe.

Is there any way I can bypass the DLL  check right at the launch of main.exe so I can still start the application without dllB?

Comment: Not unless you handle the loading of the DLLs yourself

Comment: `LoadLibrary` -- `GetProcAddress`.

Answer (score 2):

Do not specify the DLL as dependency. You can then use this code to dynamically load functions:

```
HMODULE libA = LoadLibrary("dllA.dll"); // NULL if load failed
HMODULE libB = LoadLibrary("dllB.dll"); // NULL if load failed

void (*functionA)(void) = libA ? GetProcAddress(libA,"functionA"):NULL;
void (*functionB)(void) = libB ? GetProcAddress(libB,"functionB"):NULL;
```

Comment: Or use your compiler/linker's *Delay Load* feature, if it has one. This gives you the benefit of calling the function statically in code, but load it dynamically at runtime

Comment: didn't know that was available

Comment: @pqnet Normally I have a LIB and a DLL pair and I specify the LIB as dependency while load the DLL with EXE. In this case, do you mean I do not have to specify the LIB as dependency.

Comment: @RonaldKu yes exactly. The lib is actually a stub of code that at load time perform that operation i wrote you in the answer (more or less)

Answer (score 1):

At least on windows you can explictly load the dll at runtime with [Loadlibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx)

edit: It returns NULL if the DLL isn't found or can't be loaded

Comment: How can I tell windows to skip dll check when I call this function?

Comment: @RonaldKu don't call the function statically in your code, then it won't be linked to statically in the EXE imports. Use `LoadLibrary` to load the DLL manually at runtime after the app is running, and then use `GetProcAddress` to get a pointer to the function. Or use your compiler/linker's *Delay Load* feature, if it has one. Let it handle these details for you